# Maven skips tests specified in Cucumber runner, but if I run through testng they run successful

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng

Using TestNG and Maven to run my Cucumber features. When running through Maven (mvn test) it just skips tests: `Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 2.071 sec - in TestSuite`
But when running without Maven (simple running testngCucumber.xml file) it runs successfully.
Also when running TestRunner file it runs successfully.
Would appreciate any of why it could be happenning.

Pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.moodys.act</groupId>
<artifactId>ACT.TestAutomation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ACT.TestAutomation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testngCucumber.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

testngCucumber.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.act.runner.TestRunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

TestRunner:

```
    @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/com/act/features", glue = "com/act/steps", tags = { "@ACT0001" })

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to add `test` scope to all the dependencies which take part in your test execution. P.S. - you can also remove surefire dependency since it is already defined in plugins section. You can also get some clue if enable verbose mode for maven using `-X` key

Comment: Tried adding test scope and didn't help, can you please help how to  run with "enable verbose mode for maven using -X key"?

Comment: Sure. Instead of running say `mvn test` run `mvn -X test`

Comment: Where are your feature files located? In which folder?

Comment: src\test\java\com\act\features

Comment: ran with mvn -X test, gave me a lot of lines, what should I look for there?

Comment: Can you do `mvn clean test` and then go to your `target` folder and check that the files are really there under proper folder structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218851/discussion-between-ihor-harmatii-and-alexey-r).

Comment: looks like yes, just added screenshot to my question